# mysql view over single table performance

Tags: mysql, view

I have a single table datastore with loads of integer, decimal , date,varchar fields in. I want to logically separate the data in datastore by using a views over this table.
so that datastore.i1 becomes view.field1 datastorei2 becomes view.field2 etc....
There are indexes in the datastore that provide the 'key to the view'.

Are there performance implications to this approach ?

Comment: Without knowing a bit more about the shape of this table, I think it's hard to say what the right approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of cource there are performace issues. This article can shed the light on this problem - [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/).

As a workaround - you could to split data into two physical tables (one-to-one relation).